# Check if user input is digit

Tags: c

I got this code that is supposed to check if user input is a digit or not but it prints "false" no matter if it's a digit or not.

```
if (isdigit(atoi(argv[1])))
{
   printf("true");
}
else
{
   print("false");
}
```

This is how i run it:

./filename 2 3

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the different functions.

The `atoi()` (ASCII to integer) converts a character string to `int`. But `isdigit()` checks a single character, not an `int`.

All you need is `isdigit((unsigned int) argv[1][0])` to check the first character of the string.

If you want to make sure there aren't *more* characters, verify that too:

```
bool single_digit(const char *s)
{
  return s != NULL && isdigit((unsigned int) *s) && s[1] == '\0';
}
```

then call

```
single_digit(argv[1]);
```

Comment: @PLPeeters Absolutely. The code in the question was a bit vague there. I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `atoi`. Instead just cast it to an integer.

```
if (isdigit((int)argv[1]))
{
   printf("true");
}
else
{
   print("false");
}
```

Also, run it like this: `./filename 3` (i.e. just one digit after the filename because the second one will be ignored).

**Best thing:** Check [man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for `isdigit` and other similar methods: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit